Test react-hook-form with react-native-testing-library error
I am trying to test an input value in my form, my form also contains a drop down list component - I keep getting the warning:

Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()? at label (/Users/HarrisM/apps/myrac-mobile/src/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.tsx:18:3)

How can I resolve the warning? My test is:
const mockedNavigation = {
  goBack: jest.fn(),
  navigate: jest.fn(),
  setOptions: jest.fn(),
};
describe('Contact form test', () => {
  const initialProps = {
    navigation: mockedNavigation,
  } as unknown as RegistrationRoutesGenericParams<'ContactSupportScreen'>;

  test('should show email validation error', () => {
    const rendered = render(
      <MockedAppRootProvider>
        <ContactSupportScreen {...initialProps} />
      </MockedAppRootProvider>,
    );
    const enteredEmail = 'test@test';
    const email = rendered.root.findByProps({
      testID: 'email',
    });

    fireEvent.changeText(screen.getByTestId('email'), enteredEmail);

    expect(email.props.style.color).toBe('#47474A');

